# Confused by map function in R

Tags: r, purrr

I wrote the following in R with the purrr library. Okay, it started out more complicated, but after 20 tries I reduced it down to just the basics to see what is going on.

```
map(list(1:60), function(a) { 
    if (a < 2) {
        return(1)
    } else {
        return(0)
    }})
```

```
[[1]]
[1] 1
```

> Warning message:
> In if (a < 2) { :
>
> the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used

The expected result is a list with 1 as the value of the first two elements and 0 as the value for the remainder.

What is going on here?

Comment: I don't know why you have `1:60` in `list` but `+(1:60 < 2)` would give you the same output.

Answer (score 6):

If we place it in a `list`, it would be treated as a single unit

```
library(purrr)
map(1:60, ~ if(.x > 2) 1 else 0)
```

Note that the `~` is a compact way in `tidyverse` for anonymous function call (`function(x) if(x > 2) 1 else 0`)

Or if we are creating a `list` of 60 elements, then `as.list` would be useful

```
map(as.list(1:60), ~ if(.x > 2) 1 else 0)
```

---

For this, we don't need a loop though, as it can be `unlist`ted and simply do a comparison (`>`) with 2 to create a logical `vector` which can be coerced to binary with `as.integer` or (`+` - converts the TRUE -> 1, FALSE -> 0)

```
+(unlist(as.list(1:60)) > 2)
```

and if the output needs to be a `list`, wrap with `as.list`

```
as.list(+(unlist(as.list(1:60)) > 2))
```

---

In the OP's code, what happened is

```
list(1:60)
#[[1]]
#[1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 41 42
#[43] 43 44 45 46 47 48 49 50 51 52 53 54 55 56 57 58 59 60
```

the input is a `list` with only single element having a `length` of 60.  With `map`, it loops through that single element, but `if/else` is not vectorized

According to `?Control`, the usage is

> if(cond) cons.expr  else  alt.expr

where

> cond - A length-one logical vector that is not NA. Conditions of length greater than one are currently accepted with a warning, but only the first element is used. An error is signalled instead when the environment variable

and this results in the `warning` message i.e. `if/else` expects the `list` element to have a `length` of just 1.  Instead, we can use `ifelse` which is vectorized

```
map(list(1:60), ~ ifelse(.x > 2, 1, 0))
#[[1]]
#[1] 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
```

Or just extract the `list` element

```
ifelse(list(1:60)[[1]] > 2, 1, 0)
```